# python selenium browser zoom in with shortcut (ctrl + '+') problem

Tags: python, selenium

trying to zoom in in an automated browser but i can't perform it

tried this:

```
self.action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys(Keys.ADD).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

didn't work

tried this:

```
self.bot.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL)
self.bot.find_element_by_tag_name('html').send_keys(Keys.ADD)
```

didn't work too
tried this:

```
self.bot.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='150%'")
```

didn't work as well

can someone help?

Comment: Can you share ALL you code? What exactly you have before the lines where you trying to zoom in your window?

Answer (score 1):

I wasted a lot of time. It seems CTRL + or - doesn't work for chromedriver.

Use this flow instead:

```
driver.get('chrome://settings/')
zoom = 0.5 #for example 0.5, or 1.5 or 2.0 and so on
driver.execute_script(f'chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom({zoom});')
driver.back()
```

If you to using Javascript, it will zoom CSS body. But if you need zoom in or out as for CTRL+ or - use mine code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps as you specifically asked about zooming using Keyboard inputs. I also could not work out why this doesn't work, even when using action chains with specific key_down and key_up commands it wouldn't work. However I did find a useful Javascript command that can act as a work around.

```
self.driver.execute_script("document.body.style.zoom='150%'")
```

[And here is the test I used it in](https://mx1.maxtaf.com/cases/810df333-ed67-4a18-9dd4-df805ece0697?projectId=bugtestproject2)